# How can I get working days given a date interval

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, function

Given a date interval I need to get only working days without weekends and holidays.
Most of this non-working days are fixed (so I can store them inside an holidays table), but what about Easter?
What's the best and performant way to generate a dynamic calendar using a TSQL function?

Comment: Which version of sql server do you use? Functions change in 2012

Comment: @Kuzgun SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do for Easter is store the future dates in a configuration file.  You can get ta list of them here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter.  Don't try and calculate it yourself.  The list at that URL goes up to 2021.  Plenty of time for you to patch your application at a later date :)